# Would this be the correct way of writing a member function of a struct?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, constructor, member-functions

I'm attempting to write a member function of a struct, where the member function is supposed to calculate the volume of a truncated cone. The .h file (containing the struct that was prewritten) states:

```
struct Cup
{
    double TopRadiusCms;
    double BottomRadiusCms;
    double HeightCms;

    Cup(double topRadius, double bottomRadius, double height) {
        TopRadiusCms = topRadius;
        BottomRadiusCms = bottomRadius;
        HeightCms = height;
    }

    double capacityInMls();
};
```

When writing my member function in a .cpp file, I was confused which part of the struct to reference for the calculations, and whether to make the function void or double. This is what I wrote, which I'm not sure if it is correct or not since (in order to run testcases) I have to have the next three sections written lol. Anyways, this is what I had written:

```
double Cup::capacityInMls() {
  double cupCapacity;

  cupCapacity = (1/3) * ((BottomRadiusCms * BottomRadiusCms)+(BottomRadiusCms * TopRadiusCms)+(TopRadiusCms * TopRadiusCms)) * (HeightCms) * (M_PI) ;

  return cupCapacity;
};
```

If anyone has any tips on how to fix it (if it's wrong, which I suspect it is I'm not too sure) or how to make it better. This is my first coding class ever, so I'm struggling a little bit!

Comment: `(1/3)` is always going to be zero because of integer division.  You'll want to use `(1.0/3)` or `(1.0/3.0)`

Comment: `When writing my member function in a .cpp file, [...] , and whether to make the function void or double.` The function is declared returning double so thats what the implementation has to look like aswell.

Comment: If you changed it to make it `void capacityInMls();`  on the declaration and `void Cup::capacityInMls() { // Some code here}` for the implementation then what would you do with the `cupCapacity` calculation if you can't return it to the caller? To me the function needs to return a double and should not be `void capacityInMls();`